# Why is GCC inconsistent about emitting warnings for undeclared functions?

Tags: c, gcc, warnings

The following `test.c` program

```
int main() {
   dummySum(1, 2);
   return 0;
}

int dummySum(int a, int b) {
   return a + b;
}
```

...doesn't generate any warning when compiled with `gcc -o test test.c`, whereas the following one does:

```
int main() {
   dummySum(1, 2);
   return 0;
}

void dummySum(int a, int b) {
   a + b;
}
```

Why?

Comment: It's not. I thought that too. `int` vs `void` return type of `dummySum`.

Comment: The default return type of an undeclared function is int.  When you declare it as void, it doesn't find any matching function.  I believe if you use a stronger warning check (e.g. -Wall) you'd get a warning in either case.

Comment: in the first post it was the same, you are right. i edited the post. Sorry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When faced with an undeclared function, the compiler assumes a function that accepts the given number of arguments *(I think)* and returns `int` *(that part I'm sure of)*. Your second one doesn't, and so you get the redefinition warning.

I believe, based on a very quick scan of the foreward, that C99 ([PDF link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)) removed this. No great surprise that GCC still allows them (with a warning), though; I can't imagine how much code would start failing to compile...

---

Recommend using `-Wall` (turning on all warnings) so you get a huge amount of additional information (you can turn off specific warnings when you have a *really good reason for whatever you're doing that generates them* if need be).

Comment: The 'implicit int' was removed in C99, so in strict C99 mode or C11 mode, it should not compile, IMO. However, gcc compiles it and just spits out a warning (for both).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Interesting! Actually, I just looked at C99 and I think it goes further than that: It removes implicit function declarations entirely. (Interestingly, the foreword lists the two items separately, "removed implicit `int`" and "removed implicit function declarations"). I suspect the "implicit `int`" bit refers to a function that's declared, but without any return type at all.

Comment: Probably, not being a language lawyer, I tend to use 'implicit int' for all situations where a type is assumed because it's not declared.

Answer (score 2):

A function cannot be used before it has been declared. When a function declaration is not visible, the implementation assumes in C89 that the function:

- takes an unspecified (but fixed) number of parameters
- returns an `int`

This is called an *implicit function declaration*.

In C99, implicit declarations of function have been removed of the language and the implementation is free to refuse to translate the source code.